# C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2022 to help me compile C files created by Cython. When I install DCNv2

```
python setup.py build develop
```

it gives me this error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Please help as I am not well-rounded with Visual Studio and just need to get my code running.

Thanks

Comment: there is no more error ? A multiline stacktrace ? because there is no information here at all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.